# Only make target if file exists

Tags: bash, unix, makefile

In my makefile, I want to do something like this:

```
all: foo bar python

python:
    if /usr/bin/someprogram
        do some stuff
    else
        echo "not doing some stuff, coz someprogram ain't there"
    endif
```

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: If you put in the right line continuation markers, etc. that snippet of makefile should work just fine.

Comment: It doesn't match requested functionality, which is if `/usr/bin/someprogram` exists, then "do some stuff".  As written (assuming line continuation is added), it will _run_ `/usr/bin/someprogram` and if it succeeds, it will "do some stuff".  Not the same thing at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way would be to use `test`:

```
python:
    @test -s /usr/bin/someprogram && echo "someprogram exists" || echo "someprogram does not exist"
    @test -s /bin/ls && echo "ls exists" || echo "ls does not exist"
```

As @MadScientist says, you might need an if statement in case you want to do multiple things:

```
python:
        if [ -s /bin/ls ]; then \
          echo "ls exists"; \
        fi;
```

Comment: This is the right answer.  Although if "do some stuff" in the original question is more complex you'll need an if statement, to make it readable if nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 'if' and 'shell' make functions:

```
all: foo bar python

CMD=/some/missing/command

foo:
    echo "foo"

bar:
    echo "bar"

python:
    $(if $(shell $(CMD) 2>/dev/null), \
    echo "yes", \
    echo "no")
```

This echos 'no'.  If you change CMD to, say, /bin/ls, it echos 'yes'.

Comment: I would definitely not do it this way.  The make if-statement does not work like the shell if-statement: it's not based on the exit code of the command that shell runs.  It's based on the output that the command generates.  If the command doesn't generate any output normally then this is not reliable.  Plus, you're running the command here, but the original question didn't say they wanted to run the program: it says they want to "do some stuff".

Comment: I agree with MadScientist.  The problem I was trying to get around is that the make conditional is more like #ifdef in C, and can't execute code (such as a shell test.)  devnull's solution is superior.